# How do investors get refund when `RefundableCrowdsale` does not reach its goal?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, openzeppelin

Question regarding `RefundableCrowdsale` of OpenZeppelin. When its goal isn't reached, how do investors get refund?

By calling the `claimRefund()` method? How do they call the method??

Answer (score 1):

They sign a transaction to the contract's `claimRefund()` function.

It can be done from the command-line, from Mist, from MyEtherWallet and all that is required is knowledge of the contract address and function signature.

In practice, no one should expect the users to figure out how to accomplish that.

A reasonably user-friendly implementation would present a button that users press. They will have to expend a little gas to pay for processing.

The important thing is that users should approach the contract like a vending machine/ATM and pull their funds out. This is a best practice in contract design for some good reasons.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this case, creating a `onlyOwner` refund method and refunding ether by owner's gas is not a realistic way?

Comment: It can be done, but there are technical issues to overcome and it's questionable that one should want to. What if the owner is unable or unwilling to perform the task?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Rob. What are the technical issues? I understand that our investors might not want it.

Comment: You have to be careful not to iterate over a loop `for (i=0;i <n; i++)` because it will simply fail on a large *n* owing to the gaslimit. When interacting with untrusted contracts, you want to keep them separate so mischief by Alice doesn't DoS Bob, carol, etc. Don't forget the signer pays for gas. That could be a predicament if the sponsor was supposed to pay for refunds. The withdraw pattern, aka favoring pull over push solved for those concerns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, Rob!! It helps me a lot.

Comment: Hi Rob, could you explain me more about `a button` ?  When user tap it, how user sign a transaction? By opening external wallet like MetaMask or MyEtherWallet?

Comment: (I think we can do it with MetaMask, but not with MyEtherWallet.)